# Android Dynamic Image

Tags: android, imageview, dynamic-data

I have 10 image views:

```
ImageView Card0=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Card0);
.....
ImageView Card9=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Card9);
```

all images are in my drawable folder but I am selecting the card from remote database.
a php script generates 10 random cards.

I have the array containing the file name:

```
Cards = deal.split(":");
```

Now I want to set the image:

```
Card0.setImageResource(R.drawable.Cards[0]);
```

I've tried and searched a lot but could not set any variable `setImageResource(R.drawable.*Variable*);`

someone plz help.

Comment: What are the filenames like? card0.png, card1.png ...? What is the content of `deal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to dynamically load using R.id.drawable.*.

**Solution 1:**

I will assume the names of yours card images are: card0.png, card1.png ... card9.png
I suggest you create an `assets` directory (inside the `res` directory). Copy the card images to the `assets` directory.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class YourActivity extends Activity {

//...

    public Drawable loadAssetImage(String fileName) {
        AssetManager assetMgr = this.getAssets();

        try {
            InputStream is = assetMgr.open(fileName);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, null);
            return d;
        }catch( IOException e ) {
            // error...
            return null;
        }       
    }
}
```

The `loadAssetImage()` method loads an image from the `assets` directory. So, now you can dynamically load your images since it accepts string parameters.

Note that the directory name MUST BE `assets`. Android allows direct (raw) access to internal resources in the `assets` directory.

**Solution 2**

```
public Drawable loadCardImage(int index) {
    switch( index ) {
    case 0:
        return android.R.Card0;

    case 1:
        return android.R.Card1;

    ..
    case 9:
        return android.R.Card9;         
    }
    return null;
}
```

You would receive the indices of the cards from the server. This function would return the appropriate resource.